# Is there a solution of $p^a-q^b = 2$ with $p,q$ primes and $a,b > 1$, except $3^3-5^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

*Question*: Is there a solution of $p^a-q^b = 2$ with $p,q$ prime and $a,b > 1$, except $3^3-5^2$ ?

*Remark*: For $p,q,a,b < 200$, the only solution is $3^3-5^2$.
Idem for $\max(p,q)<200000$, $\min(p,q)<200$ and $a,b<20$.

This question came after this post: [Infiniteness of twin prime powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990195/84284)

Comment: I believe the standard generalization of [Catalan's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)  is unknown, though my impression was that Mihăilescu's argument could probably be extended (with a great deal of work).  In any case, the wiki article mentions $25$ known examples with $n=2$, but it doesn't list them.  Should be easy to check to see if any others on that list are prime powers.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks for the link. Note that $25$ is not the the number of solutions but the solution itself: $25=5^2$ and $25+2=3^3$.

Comment: @lulu Methinks you misinterpreted the table in the wikipedia page. $n = 25$ is the only perfect power $n$ such that $n + 2$ is a perfect power is how I read it. If memory doesn't deceive me, that case is proved.

Comment: @DanielFischer  (and SebastianPalcoux)  Oh, of course.  That makes much more sense.  Thanks.  I also recalled that this case was known, but couldn't find a reference.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nice! Can you find a reference?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not a number theorist. And it's quite possible that my memory deceives me, it's not as reliable as it was twenty years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strongly suspected that the only solutions in positive integers $x, y, n$ and $m$ with $n, m \geq 2$ to
$$
x^n-y^m=2
$$
is with $(x,y,n,m)=(3,5,3,2)$. Proving this (even in the special case with $x$ and $y$ prime) is apparently beyond current technology (unless one has a proof of the $ABC$-Conjecture). Mihailescu's proof of Catalan's Conjecture relies fundamentally upon properties of cyclotomic fields and does not extend to this case.